# disabled options are enabled after postback chosen.js asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I am trying to apply multiselect feature to a asp.net listbox using chosen.js.

This listbox contains values like this

```
All
-----------(disabled through c#)
MSG(disabled through c#)
---------(disabled through c#)
CONTROL PANEL
WINDOWS SHELL
-------(disabled through c#)
OMST(disabled through c#)
----------(disabled through c# li.Attributes.Add("disable","true");
edocket
dashboard
```

initially the dropdown is working fine.but after postback the disable items are getting enabled.

disabled items are initially getting render with class="disabled-result" after postback class becoming "active-result".

Can anyone help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the attributes of a SELECT and/or OPTION elements will not be persisted automatically on post-back.
You must maintain your own values for things such as "class" and "disabled".
You may do this via viewstate, database stores or other methods of your choosing.  Somthing like this:

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If IsPostBack Then
        RestoreProperties(dropDownControl)
    Else
        LoadDatabaseItems(dropDownControl)
    End

End Sub
```

Where "LoadDatabaseItems" would handle the initial loading of the drop-down list, setting initial attributes of both the SELECT control and its member OPTION elements.  It would also STORE the class and disabled properties as needed.

and "RestoreProperties" represents your home-grown view-state store.  That routine would loop through the 'alread-existing' OPTION elements to set their CLASS, DISABLED and other properties.